# Fan-out with hosted agents

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a node.js project that I'd like to switch from a current home-grown CI to Azure Pipelines. There are some extensive tests required for every other commit or so that require three simple steps:

1. `npm install` and `build` for the main project as well as a test tool (also javascript)
2. Run that test tool
3. Aggregate result files and merge into one `test-results.json`

That second step takes about an hour worst-case and I'd like to make use of those 10 free hosted agents Azure offers.
This should be simple, at least on the CI systems I've tried so far:
Run step 1, start 10 agents for step 2, once they're all done start one final agent that collects the results.

Given that there seems to be no workspace persistence at all on Azure(really?), I apparently need to either checkout the git repository 12 times for all 12 agents or do it once in step 1 and then pack up the whole thing, `node_modules` and all, and publish it as an artifact for the following steps to download and unpack again.
That can't possibly be the correct way, can it?

If it is, is there a difference between *one pipeline with every step in it* and *one pipeline for every step*, or is it just a matter of taste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That can't possibly be the correct way, can it?

This way is possible, but I am not sure if it is the best way. Just like you said, it is just a matter of taste.

To accomplish this, we need to publish whole things by the task `Publish build artifacts`
 to the Azure Pipelines in step 2, then add a agent with 10 tasks `Download build artifacts` to download whole things from each agent in step 2.

But the challenge is we have to manually execute latest agent, because it could not to know know when the 10 agents in the second step end.

In general, we will slice the test suite, then run tests in parallel to get the result for each test suite:

Check the document [Run tests in parallel for any test runner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-any-test-runner?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

> If it is, is there a difference between one pipeline with every step
>   in it and one pipeline for every step, or is it just a matter of
>   taste?

The answer is yes. When you use one pipeline with every step in it, all the step in one agent/machine, we do not need to care about the transfer of assets into each step. But if you use one pipeline for every step, it will be a challenge. At the same time, you need also consider the concurrency between agents and the use of agent resources.

So, if the step in the pipeline does not take a long time, we recommend you to use one pipeline with every step in it.

Hope this helps.